# I am trying to launch Mozilla, but I am getting this error every time. I am using selenium selenium-java-4.3.0 version and geckodriver-v0.31.0-win64

Tags: selenium, firefox, webdriver

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Require$StateChecker.nonNull(Require.java:311)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:135)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:45)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:181)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:437)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.createDefaultService(GeckoDriverService.java:94)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:98)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:94)
at com.qe.demoqa.Demo_QA.main(Demo_QA.java:11)